# True or False Question on Outer measure.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

State TRUE or FALSE giving proper justification

1) There exist an unbounded subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t $m^*(A)=5$

2) There exist an open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t $[1/2, 3/4] \subset A$ and $m^*(A)=1/4$

3) There exist an open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t $m^*(A)<1/5$ but $A \cap (a, b) \neq \phi$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$

4) If $A$ & $B$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ s.t $A \subsetneq B$, then it is necessary that $m^*(A)< m^*(B)$

My thought:

1) TRUE as we have the set $[0, 5] \cup \mathbb{Z}$

3) TRUE , if we consider the set $[0, 1/6] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

CHECK this true and please help on 2 and 4.

Comment: Please double check the statement of 3, $A\cap(a,b)$ what?

Comment: For $(2)$, remember that the endpoints of the interval, $1/2$ and $3/4$, will have to be contained in open neighborhoods extending out of the interval, of non-zero length.

Comment: @Chris , Can u explain little bit?

Comment: Taking $1/2$, for example, because the set $A$ is supposed to be open, there's an $r$ such that $N_r(1/2) = \{x : |x - 1/2| < r\}$ is included in $A$ - that is, $N_r(1/2) \subset A$. In particular, we'll have $(1/2 - r, 1/2] \subset A$.

Comment: I am sorry that I gave a complicated counter example to 4) in my solution. A simple example is $B=(0,1)$ and $A=(0,1) \setminus \{1/2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Any open set $S$ containing the point $1/2$ will have a subset $(-d+1/2,\;d+1/2)$ for some $d>0,$ whereupon if also $S\supset [1/2,\;3/4]$ then $$S\supset (-d+1/2,\;d+1/2)\cup [1/2,\;3/4]\supset (-d+1/2,\;3/4] $$ which implies $m^*(S)\geq m^*(\;(-d+1/2,\;3/4]\;)=3/4-(1/2-d)=1/4+d>1/4.$

Measure and outer measure are meant to be generalizations of the notion of length,  so it is helpful that their definitions imply that  the measure, and the outer measure, of an interval, are, in fact, its length.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all statements are about nice Borel sets so there is no need to talk of outer measure. Your answer to 3) is wrong because your set is not open. To answer 3) arrange rational numbers in a sequence $\{r_n\}$ and take the interval around $r_n$ with length $\frac 1 {2^{n} 10}$. The union A of these intervals is open and $m(A)< \frac 1 5$. The answer to 4) is no. Let A be the union of the intervals removed in the construction of Cantor set and $B=(0,1)$. Then $m(A)=m(B)=1$ even though A is proper subset of B.

Comment: For 4) just take $B=(0,1)$ and $A=B-\setminus \{1/2\}$.